# Windows 10 Display changes only partial

Tags: windows, settings, region

I had changed language on my desktop so that I could get the spell checking to work for Italian. I am no unable to get the language setting back to English. 
That is to say I can set the language back to English however many of the dialogs are still rendering in Italian. I have tried removing all other languages apart from English followed by a reboot to no avail.

Even though English is the only language installed the settings and other OS level dialogs are all written in Italian.

[image]

How can I get the display language back to English for all dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

OK it turns out that there are two places where this is set. 
Region and Language settings accessible from control panel by searching for Region and language. But then there is a different set of settings that you can access through the Language bar. These settings would appear to have precedence.
On the language bar click the down arrow (bottom right) and click settings then click options. This allows you to override the the display language.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YwQE.png